# UUencode checksum fault

Tags: algorithm, math, byte, uuencode

I have a stream of data that im attempting to encode with UUencode, in order to pass the data on to an external chip. The chip accepts 512 bytes of raw data at once. I encode 512 bytes with UUencode.

As far as i understand, the data should be converted into 11 lines of 45 bytes (which will be 60 bytes after encoding) and 1 remaining line of 17 bytes.

Obviously the 17 bytes cant map directly to uuencoded segments as it isnt a multiple of 3, yet when i get the uuencoded data back, the final line returns 24 encoded bytes (or 18 raw bytes).

This means that i now have 513 bytes of data in total. My question is, is this a fault with my uuencode algorithm (although from a purely mathematical perspective i cant see how it can be) or alternatively, where does the extra byte come from, and how do i get rid of it again?

Comment: UUEncoding? How quaint. What's wrong with base64, and why are you implementing your own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UUEncoding 512 bytes will get you 684 encoded bytes (not 513).  An input data stream of length 384 bytes will encode to exactly 512 bytes.

UUEncoding is simply a means to transform a 3 binary byte input data segment into a 4 text byte output data segment.  Any input segment that is not 3 bytes long is padded with null bytes until it is.  The UUEncoding algorithm has no representation for the original data length.

Contrast this with UUEncoded files which format and add information to the data stream by breaking the stream into lines of a specific length and add a line length indicator to the front of each encoded line of data.  In your example, your 17 final bytes would be encoded to 24 bytes, but this line of data would be preceded by a byte that gives the length of the line as 17 instead of 18.

The only way to get rid of the padding is to know it is there in the first place by encoding the length of the data.